# C realloc() function fails

Tags: c, realloc

Why does this code not work?

```
char *x=malloc(100);
x++;
x=realloc(x, 200);
```

I mean x is a valid string pointer, just incremented by one?

Comment: Because it is not the pointer that you obtained from `malloc()`...

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Well it's a question about C.

Comment: The documentation is clear. Pass a pointer obtained from a call to malloc or friends.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Oh fair enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what `realloc` does. How can it `free` the pointer at address `x+1` when `malloc` actually created a pointer at address `x`?

In more concrete terms, let's assume you allocated 100 bytes at address 0x1000. Now `x` is incremented, pointing at 0x1001. Then you call `realloc` at the new address. Because none of `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` created 0x1001, `free` (or equivalent code) used by the call to `realloc` has no idea how to do anything with 0x1001; it can't even fathom how many bytes of memory it occupies. It only knows about the 100 bytes at 0x1000.

The basic idea behind implementations of `malloc` and friends is that you keep track of the pointers assigned and how many bytes were allocated. Then when `free` is called later, the pointer passed to `free` is looked up. If there is no reference to that pointer passed to `free`, what else is there to do except crash? That, to me, is more logical than supposing you can keep using a pointer that may or may not be valid.

Answer (score 7):

See C Standard (C99, 7.20.3.4p3) on `realloc` and my emphasis:

> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
>
> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, **if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by the
>   calloc, malloc, or realloc function,** or if the space has been deallocated by a call
>   to the free or realloc function, the **behavior is undefined**.

In your case `x` was returned by `malloc`, not `x + 1`. So your program invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @usario How possibly could it be the pointer earlier returned by `malloc()` if you incremented it using `++`?

Answer (score 2):

```
char *x=malloc(100);
x++;
x=realloc(x, 200);
```

In the code shown above the address pointed by the pointer `x` is changed before invoking the `realloc()` function. This is undefined behavior in **C**.

Answer (score 1):

This is an `undefined behavior` as you if you think that you have obtained a pointer from `malloc()` which is wrong.

Clearly `x` was returned by `malloc` and its value was changed before calling `realloc()` Hence it is showing the **undefined behavior**.

Comment: _"if you think that you have obtained a pointer from malloc() which is wrong."_ `malloc` returns a pointer to the beginning of newly allocated memory . What are you trying to convey ?

Comment: @POW:- I just wanted to convey that pointer returned by malloc  does not match then it is undefined behavior. Here x was returned by malloc and then it was updated and hence it did not match with realloc resulting in undefined behavior.Please do correct me if I am wrong in getting it!!

Comment: ...does not match with the one, which is later used in `realloc`, then it is undefined behavior

Comment: @POW:- Yes exactly that Sir what I meant!!